# How do I avoid duplicate code with similar classes, same methods with different property names

Tags: c#, inheritance, entity-framework-core, interface, code-duplication

Here's a very basic example of what I'm talking about. We have Student, Enrollment, and Club, along with StudentEnrollment and StudentClub representing many-to-many relationships between Students->Enrollment and Students->Club. I am using EFCore for the data model, if that helps.

One basic method of both of these class would be adding a student to an enrollment, or a club, if they are not already a part of that respective object (see StudentEnrollment.AddStudent and StudentClub.AddStudent). The methods are pretty much functionality identical, but the name of the class and the name of the properties you need to compare are different.

Is there a way to create a shared method/class/inheritance/interface/generic/SOMETHING that can be written just once, and used by both classes, despite the different property/class names?

Basic example code (with some pseudocode):

```
public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Enrollment 
    {
        public int EnrollmentId { get; set; }
        public string EnrollmentName { get; set; }
    }

    public class StudentEnrollment
    { 
        public int EnrollmentId { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }

        public void AddStudent(Student student, Enrollment enrollment)
        {
    //pseudocode
            if (!exists (Where(enrollment.EnrollmentId == this.EnrollmentId && student.StudentId == this.StudentId)))
            {
                // add student enrollment
            }
        }
    }

    public class Club
    {
        public int ClubId { get; set; }
        public string ClubName {get; set;}
    }

    public class StudentClub
    {
        public int ClubId { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }

        public void AddStudent(Student student, Club club)
        {
    //pseudocode
            if (!exists (Where(club.ClubId == this.ClubId && student.StudentId == this.StudentId)))
            {
                // add student club
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't think inheritance works, nor an interface. Maybe a generic, I'm not very good in that space? Something else?

Comment: _"I don't think inheritance works"_ - [that's right, it doesn't](https://boxbase.org/entries/2020/aug/3/case-against-oop).

Comment: You can always create a base class that EF doesn't know about, i.e. without EF inheritance. But to question is too vague to anticipate what would suit you.

Comment: I thought about that too, but the functionality that would be shared is maintaining the lists of StudentEnrollments and StudentClubs, like the AddStudent method above, so I don't think that can really be done in way that EF doesn't know about.

Answer (score 0):

The question to ask when considering inheritance is whether there is an *"is-a"* relationship between two classes.

It's pretty obvious that a `StudentClub` is not a `StudentEnrollment` (since enrollment here is class enrollment), nor, vice versa.

Is there a common concept that they are both *is-a* of?  You might consider having a `StudentGrouping` a common (likely abstract) base class (or perhaps having an `IStudentGrouping` interface that they both inherit from).

The concept of a *StudentGrouping* seems way too abstract to spend inheritance on. Is there any reason why you might consider, say, a collection of polymorphic `StudentGrouping` instances on your code.

You might might be able to make a case for both classes implementing an `IStudentGrouping` interface (implementing `ICollection<Student>`), which would give a clear indication that both are collections of students (and allow use of the *Collection Initialization Pattern*).

That said, I don't know if that gives you much benefit compared to making both classes simply implement `ICollection<Student>`. I suggest just going with that.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't that clear. The mention of inheritance was indeed based on the idea of creating a base class that StudentEnrollment and StudentClub would both inherit from, as you suggested with StudentGrouping.
However, another thing that I left out, for brevity, is that those would all be DB Entities using EFCore, representing a many-to-many relationship. So I don't think implementing a simple ICollection<Student> on each would work exactly. When updating the collection, I would be getting existing records from the database and updating that list.

Comment: Something I forgot to mention is that adding inheritance into something that's backed by a relational database is no fun at all. I'd need a real strong reason for using inheritance if I was persisting the database. Look up the _object relational impedance mismatch_ for some discussion of this.

Comment: I appreciate the discussion. I am not really looking for a reason to cram inheritance into my code. I just get annoyed at writing duplicated code which only differs by the names of the class and properties. 

In the example in my post, If I were to create a base class which StudentEnrollment and StudentClub inherit from, and implement the AddStudent method at the base level, why can't the code be smart enough to swap in those names. Some sort of automatic dynamic code replacement...

{parameter1} == this.{parameter1} && {parameter2} == this.{parameter2}

Something like that.

Comment: @Workdawg Unfortunately, having many _similarly shaped_ types with common members is a fact-of-life. Eventually everyone learns _the hard way_ that inheritance is not a solution to the "repetitive shared members" problem. Some languages tackle this with support for _traits_ or _mixins_, but C# lacks both. As a someone who now almost exclusively writes in C# I've found alternative-solutions involving tooling for _scaffolding_  and codegen, such as T4 text-templates and Roslyn code-generation, both which are very powerful in their own right. HTH + YMMV. Good luck!